# Is there any way to give the flow administrator permissions?

Tags: visual-workflow

The requirement I have is as follows:

In the service cloud, a sales agent who doesn't have permissions to create or edit cases, needs to be able to edit cases and create tasks through a flow.

The problem is that the flow shares the same permissions as the user and therefore will not be able to edit or create tasks.

Is there any way to give the flow administrator permissions? I tried to use apex actions to make the case updates but I would like to know if there is another method.

Comment: I am not sure about your question. Would you like that the user call a flow? Is it?

Answer (score 1):

If the user license has access to the functionality you want them to be able to do in the flow, you could use a [flow to grant a session-based permission set](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/perm_sets_session_activate_flow.htm) that would give them the access to do this in the flow and would remove it at the end of the flow

There is however one fatal flaw with this (sorry!).  If the user closes the flow before completing it, they would retain the permissions granted by the flow.  Its crazy, but that is what it is.

So, the only other approach is a lot more work - you could have the flow insert a record of a custom object, and have a flow / process on that object to create case, create tasks, etc.  Auto-launched flows run in system mode.  Just note that you may need to set ownerID in the flow to a queue or a user w access to cases as the autolaunched flow would set it to the running user and that may throw an error.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about giving admin permissions to flow. But you can achieve this using Apex+VF Page(not standard controller), where a default class would behave in a System Mode which would give a user to access a Case via VF Page or create a case via a VF Page.

Give it a try and hope this works for you.

Comment: I need to do it without VF but thank you! :)